# Getting EM clusterer output programmatically in Weka

Tags: java, cluster-analysis, weka, expectation-maximization

When using Kmeans in Weka, one can call `getAssignments()` on the resulting output of the model to get the cluster assignment for each given instance.
I am using EM clustering on weka. I want to get output like weka's explorer as bellow or is there something similar for EM? What should I do?

I tried this: [Getting Xmeans clusterer output programmatically in Weka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12451591/getting-xmeans-clusterer-output-programmatically-in-weka)

[image]

Comment: @Bono. but we can not use enumeration in EM clustering. am I right?

Comment: Unfortunately I just edited your answer to include some things you forgot. I don't have any knowdledge about the thing you're asking about ;)

Answer (score 1):

I get the answer finally. It can catch by print output your current Instance of EM. ex.

```
System.out.println("INFO IS: \n "+ em);
```